# SeekBar Group - stop drag before maxValue

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I'm struggling with the current situation. I must simulate the peoples' choice of items from a bucket. I have to do it with 3 seekbars, however I must stop the dragging of each bar when no more items are left available in the bucket. All seekbars need to have the same BUCKET_ITEM_COUNT max value.
Is there any way of stopping those seekbars at a value different from maxValue so that the sum of all their progresses is less or equal to the bucket size?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
seekBar1.setMax(bucketTotal);

seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser && progress + seekBar2.getProgress() + seekBar3.getProgress() > bucketTotal) {
            seekBar.setProgress(progress1);
        } else {
            progress1 = progress;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Apply this to all others.